# fstab entry for NFS mount on laptop

Tags: linux, boot, laptop, nfs, fstab

I have an entry in my client machine's fstab to automatically mount my NFS at boot. When the NFS network isn't present I'm waiting an additional 1.5 minutes for my system to boot: "systemd-analyze blame". Is there an option I could add in my fstab line to shorten my boot time if the share is not available? I know I could always manually mount after booting, but I'd rather make this a seamless process.

Answer (score 4):

Place "noauto" in an entry in the /etc/fstab file.

This makes the information, about this mount point, not cause the hangup that you mention.

Then, completely separate from your /etc/fstab file, modify your startup script to run mount in the background (e.g., "mount /local-mount-point &") so it starts in the background.  It will either succeed quickly, or not; either way your system can continue booting more quickly.

Comment: I would add a `ping -c 4 nfs.server && mount nfsserver:/remote /local` . this way you try to mount only if server is available.